# synaptics multitouch not working 12.04

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, trackpad

I have a laptop (Acer 7745G) with a synaptics touchpad that should support up to 3 finger multitouch if I am interpreting the output of `grep "TouchPad: buttons" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` correctly. The output is below.

```
[     7.805] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple scroll-buttons
```

Two finger scrolling works fine but 3 finger gestures do not work in unity for some reason.  I have put the following configuration in Xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "Touchpad"                      # required
  MatchIsTouchpad "yes"                           # required
 Driver          "synaptics"                     # required
  Option  "TapButton3"  "3"
  Option  "SHMConfig" "true"
EndSection
```

and I have recieved the following output from synclient -m

```
  time     x    y   z f  w  l r u d m     multi  gl gm gr gdx gdy
48.144  5327 2456 112 3  5  0 0 0 0 0  00000000
```

If I am not mistaken, the 3 means it is recognizing that there are 3 fingers on the touchpad.

All of these things seem to me like they should point to Unity MultiTouch working but I cannot use any of the 3 finger multitouch gestures for some reason. I'm sure I'm missing something that should be simple but for some reason I cannot figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.